# Display image when the original is not found

Tags: javascript, image, extjs

In JavaScript, I would like to display a default image just when the original image is not found. I'm pretty sure I miss something small but still can't figure out what it is. http://jsfiddle.net/yfm6E/

```
objImg = new Image();
objImg.src = 'http://tiltips.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/imgurlogo.jpeg';


if(!objImg.complete)
 { 
   //  alert('no');
      src = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQGdkmZ9a8Kk-AX1W3wGWZeXnp2OdbSAzqiWnstiFJGg-ZI04Yc'; //load other image
  }else{
   //    alert('yes');
    src= 'http://tiltips.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/imgurlogo.jpeg';
  } 



var layout = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            //renderTo: 'layout',
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            title: 'My Panel', //no title will be blank         
            html: "<img src= src  width='120' height='150'/> ",
            renderTo: Ext.getBody() //get the body and display Layout at there
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `src` variable was part of the string. Therefore replace this line:

```
html: "<img src= src  width='120' height='150'/> ",
```

with this line:

```
html: Ext.String.format('<img src= "{0}"  width="120" height="150"/> ', src),
```

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/yfm6E/1/